# What is the prefered way of generating extension module filename suffix in virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

We have a Python project that has a C++ extension module based on pybind11. We use `python3-config --extension-suffix` to get the filename suffix of the extension module. It works fine on systems with only one primary version of Python installed.

Now we are trying to build the extension module for multiple Python versions within a single system. So we created a system with multiple Python versions installed, each with a corresponding virtual environment. Then the problem emerges: python3-config is not available in virtual environments so the version of executed python3-config might not match the version of activated virtualenv. For example, `python3-config --extension-suffix` might output `.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` even if a python3.8 virtualenv is activated.

The only way I can think of is to copy the corresponding version's python3-config to the virtualenv's bin directory but then we have to remember to do this every time a new virtualenv is created otherwise the wheel generated is not going to work. So I wonder if there is a better way and what people usually do when they build extension modules inside virtualenvs.

Comment: Have you tried `pyenv` for managing python version? At least it works as intended on my PC (`pyenv local 3.10.11; python3-config --prefix` shows `3.10` version path, and `pyenv local 3.11.3; python3-config --prefix` points to 3.11 installation).

Comment: @STerliakov I have only used `virtualenv` and `venv`. Switching to a different virtualenv manager probably is not the way to go for our project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The scripts are versioned. There're `python3.6-config`, `python3.7-config`, `python3.11-config`…

Comment: @phd still, they are not available in virtualenvs. By coping python3-config which is a symbolic link, it essentially copies the version-specific script. Referring to the version-specific script directly instead of referring to the symlink doesn't seem to make things any easier.